# Absolutely positioned element is not clipped by its container

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to implement 'sticky headers' on a table within a containing div with minimal javascript. I have the containing div, the table header and body split up, and the table header absolutely positioned. This almost works. My only issue is that the the header is appearing above the containing div. Is there a way to make my table header appear underneath the containing div (without javascript)? I need the header to stay absolutely positioned at the top of that div. I've tried z-indexes and relative positioning on the container. Is there something I am missing?

In the snippet below, the white header should be hidden by the scrollbar and the green div.

One thing to note - I do realize that I will have to use javascript to implement the **horizontal** scrolling of the header. but this question is purely about the clipping of the header while maintaining the **vertical** scrolling without javascript.

This is the result I am trying to achieve:

When scrolled to the top:

[image]

When scrolled to the bottom:

[image]

```css
.container-container {
  background-color:#ccffcc;
  z-index:3;
}
.container {
  background-color:#ffcccc;
  height: 150px;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
  z-index:1;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th {
  width: 100px;
  min-width: 100px;
}
td {
  width: 100px;
  min-width: 100px;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
}
thead {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: solid 1px #e0e0e0;
  z-index:2;
}
tbody {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 29px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-container">
  <div class="container">
    <table id="callLogExplorer">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>head1</th>
          <th>head2</th>
          <th>head3</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Hi, I don't think you really need javascript for this. But I don't understand too much the result you want to achieve. Could you maybe post a jpg with the final layout?

Comment: @Stratboy, I just added some images. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Lose the `<thead>` and  `<tbody>` and just put `<th>` in the first row. Then style it accordingly. Instead of targeting thead in css, you can target `tr:first-of-type`, and lose position absolute also.

```css
.container-container {
  background-color:#ccffcc;
  z-index:3; position:relative;
}
.container {
  background-color:#ffcccc;
  height: 150px;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
  z-index:1;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th {
  width: 100px;
  min-width: 100px;
}
td {
  width: 100px;
  min-width: 100px;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
}
tr:first-of-type {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: solid 1px #e0e0e0;
  z-index:2;
  position:absolute; top:0;
  width: 180px; overflow-x: auto;
}
table {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 29px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-container">
  <div class="container">
    <table id="callLogExplorer">
        <tr>
          <th>head1</th>
          <th>head2</th>
          <th>head3</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
          <td>asdfasd fas</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @mikepa88. Unfortunately, when I do that, the header then scrolls with the rest of the table. I need the header to stay fixed at the top

Comment: @MattSpinks Edited. It's not perfect, but if I had to improve it, I would remake the layout more extensively.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to achive ?

If need i'll can give further explanation.

```css
.all-wrapper{
 border:2px solid black;
 width:510px;
 overflow:hidden;
}

.container1 {
 background-color:red;
 padding-top:30px; 
 position:relative;
 width:510px;
 
}

.container{
 background-color:yellow; 
 width:510px;
 height:150px;
 overflow-y:scroll;
 overflow-x:hidden;
}

table{
 background-color:magenta;
 width:510px;
}
thead{
 background-color:#00FF00;
 height:30px;
 width:510px;
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
}
thead th{
 width:500px;
 text-align:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="all-wrapper">
    <div class="container1">
      <div class="container">
        <table id="callLogExplorer">
        
        <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>head1</th>
              <th>head2</th>
              <th>head3</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        
        <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>R0C0</td>
              <td>R0C1</td>
              <td>R0C2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>R1C0</td>
              <td>R1C1</td>
              <td>R1C2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>asdfasd fas</td>
              <td>asdfasd fas</td>
              <td>asdfasd fas</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>asdfasd fas</td>
              <td>asdfasd fas</td>
              <td>asdfasd fas</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>asdfasd fas</td>
              <td>asdfasd fas</td>
              <td>asdfasd fas</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>asdfasd fas</td>
              <td>asdfasd fas</td>
              <td>asdfasd fas</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>asdfasd fas</td>
              <td>asdfasd fas</td>
              <td>asdfasd fas</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>asdfasd fas</td>
              <td>asdfasd fas</td>
              <td>asdfasd fas</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>asdfasd fas</td>
              <td>asdfasd fas</td>
              <td>asdfasd fas</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>asdfasd fas</td>
              <td>asdfasd fas</td>
              <td>asdfasd fas</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>asdfasd fas</td>
              <td>asdfasd fas</td>
              <td>asdfasd fas</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>asdfasd fas</td>
              <td>asdfasd fas</td>
              <td>asdfasd fas</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>asdfasd fas</td>
              <td>asdfasd fas</td>
              <td>asdfasd fas</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>asdfasd fas</td>
              <td>asdfasd fas</td>
              <td>asdfasd fas</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>asdfasd fas</td>
              <td>asdfasd fas</td>
              <td>asdfasd fas</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>asdfasd fas</td>
              <td>asdfasd fas</td>
              <td>asdfasd fas</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>asdfasd fas</td>
              <td>asdfasd fas</td>
              <td>asdfasd fas</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>asdfasd fas</td>
              <td>asdfasd fas</td>
              <td>asdfasd fas</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>asdfasd fas</td>
              <td>asdfasd fas</td>
              <td>asdfasd fas</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>END C0</td>
              <td>END C1</td>
              <td>END C2</td>
            </tr>
        <tbody>
        
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi Elnur. This is really close. The only thing I wish I had was a vertical scrollbar. Is that possible? Also, can you explain a little bit how this works?

Comment: @MattSpinks, is it suitable for you ? Just mention that scrollbar not occupies the whole container but only scrolled content.

Comment: Well, we need vertical scrolling as well as horizontal scrolling. The container is smaller than the table in both directions.

Comment: @MattSpinks, worth for it is using JS. Dont waste your time trying do it in just pure css.

Comment: Because, you want both scrollbars appear in containing block, but content of table scrolls in one content and header settled in other content, so they cannot be scrolled both at the same time, to synchronize their scrolling length you need a some logic applied on them.